# How to display the role of a user in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to display the user role in Symfony with the `FOSUserBundle`.

```
public function showAction() {
    $model = new User();
    $role = $model->getRoles();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/show.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'role' => $role,
    ));
}
```

This my code in my ProfileController put that I can not call in Twig. Here is my Twig file:

```
<div class="fos_user_user_show">

<p><b>{{ 'Username'|trans }}</b>: {{ user.username }}</p>
<p><b>{{ 'Email'|trans }}</b>: {{ user.email }}</p>
<p><b>{{ 'Role'|trans }}</b>: {{ role.user }}</p>
```

Comment: a bit offtopic, but you should really considering group based role, as easier than managing specific user access, fosuserbundle provide a very powerful group based role

Answer (score 0):

try only with this:

```
<p><b>{{ 'Role'|trans }}</b>: {{ role }}</p>
```

Comment: thank you for the help but still the error is make is:
Missing argument 1 for Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User::__construct(),

Comment: this is another question, you should open another thread, as it could be not related to this question. In order to help you, you just didn t provide a username or username is null to your user entity class in creating a new user.

Comment: As Charles wrote this is another question, and you shoud open a new question about It. Close It and open another please, and we will glad to help you into another question @erevos13

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
<p><b>{{ 'Role'|trans }}</b>: {{ user.roles }}</p>
```